# In layman's terms what is the definition and difference between Keys, Secrets and certificates in Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, key, azure-keyvault

I am trying to learn about the definition and difference between Keys, Secrets and Certificates in Azure Key Vault. I have been reading through the post below a couple of times but to me it seems a bit technical:

[What is difference between Keys and Secrets in Azure Key Vault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277023/what-is-difference-between-keys-and-secrets-in-azure-key-vault)

So In layman's terms is it possible for anyone to describe what is the definition and difference between Keys, Secrets and certificates in Azure Key Vault?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Secrets are used for sensitive information that is used by, for example, an application. Typical secrets are connection strings for databases, client secrets for app registrations, passwords for ftp servers etc.

Certificates are, well, certificates like SSL certificates to secure web applications or code signing certificates for software deployments.

Keys are cryptographic keys used to encrypt for example data at rest for azure services.

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/about-keys-secrets-certificates#object-types) for more details.